# Evento click de button deja de funcionar cuando se actualiza el una sección de la pagina al usar ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un CRUD con **Ajax** usando la libreria **jquery**, en `index.php` muestro todos los registros de la BD, donde ademas le agrego un botón con clase "editar" a cada fila.

```
<div class="contenido">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="active">
        <tr class="active">
          <th>Usuario</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Editar/Eliminar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="contenido">
      <?php
      include 'usuarios.php'
      ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

usuarios.php

```
while($usuario=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
  echo "<tr>
  <td>$usuario->usuario</td>
  <td>$usuario->nombre</td>
  <td> <button id='$usuario->usuario' class='editar'>Editar</button></td></tr>";
}
```

cuando recién cargo la pagina el botón Editar me funciona correctamente, mostrándome el mensaje que tengo definido en el código **javascript**, pero una vez que hago uso del método para agregar un nuevo usuario mediante una ventana modal, los botones de editar dejan de funcionar y no muestran
mas el alert.

pienso que el detalle esta cuando se actualiza el DOM, cuando agrego un nuevo registro recargo el `div` container para visualizar el nuevo registro.

```
$('.contenido').load('usuarios.php');
```

este es mi codigo js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //funcion para registrar nuevo usuario
  $('#registrar').click(function(){
    var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
    var nombre_com = $("#nombre").val()+" "+$('#ape_pat').val()+" "+$('#ape_mat').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'insert_usuarios.php',
      data: 'usuario='+usuario+'&nombre='+nombre_com,
      success: function(data){
        $('.contenido').load('usuarios.php');

      }
    });
  });

  $('.editar').click(function(){
    alert('Mensaje de prueba editar');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo ese es un problema muy común cuando actualizas el DOM en vez de usar el evento `click()` de **jquery** usa el evento `on()` que como parámetro recibe otro evento.

cambia tu código

```
 $('.editar').click(function(){
   alert('Mensaje de prueba editar');
 });
```

por este a ver si te funciona

```
$(".contenido").on("click",".editar",function(){
  alert('Mensaje de prueba editar');
 });
```

El evento `on()` hace que se recorra de nuevo todo el `html` dentro de un objeto y así podemos usar el `html` dinámico que nos traemos después de rende rizar por primera vez la pagina.

Espero te ayude saludos.

### Definición y uso

> El método on () conecta uno o más controladores de eventos para los elementos seleccionados y elementos secundarios.
>
> A partir de jQuery versión 1.7, el método on () es el nuevo reemplazo de los métodos bind (), live () y delegate (). Este método aporta mucha consistencia a la API, y recomendamos que utilice este método, ya que simplifica la base de código de jQuery.
>
> Nota: Los manejadores de eventos adjuntos usando el método on () funcionarán para elementos actuales y FUTUROS (como un nuevo elemento creado por un script).
>
> Consejo: Para eliminar manejadores de eventos, use el método off () .
>
> Sugerencia: para adjuntar un evento que solo se ejecuta una vez y luego se elimina, use el método one () .

---

### Sintaxis

```
$(selector).on(event,childSelector,data,function,map)
```

---

**Fuente**:[www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp)

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
$(".botonTraeHtml").click(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  $(".contenedorhtmlNuevo").html("<button class='btnClickNormal' type='button' name='button'>Boton dinamico con evento click normal</button><br><br><button class='btnClickOn' type='button' name='button'>Boton dinamico con evento On</button>")

});
})

//evento click normal que solo funciona con html no dinamico
$(".btnClickNormal").click(function(){
  alert("hola soy un boton traido dinamicamente")
})

//evento on click que funciona con cualquier html dinamico o no
$(".contenedorhtmlNuevo").on("click",".btnClickOn",function(){
  alert("hola soy un boton traido dinamicamente")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="botonTraeHtml" type="button" name="button">Traer html dinamico</button>

<div class="contenedorhtmlNuevo">
    
  </div>
```